# Defragment an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, defragmentation

I'm trying to figure out how to do this but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

What I have is an array of chars holding some strings including the null at the end of each string.

Like this:

[image: Example]

I want to be able to consolidate all the data and have a single large chunk of free space at the end, but I need to also save the null at the end of each string.

How would you do this?

Comment: Why don't just copy the text output here? You don't need to post images

Comment: Use `strcat()` or `strncat()`

Comment: Because the OP wants to preserve the '\0' at the end of the string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly the problem is. You copy each string within the array to the first available location, starting with the first. `strcpy` may not work because its argument strings must not overlap, so the safe thing would be to copy chars "manually".

Comment: Fix the title, or fix the C language tag.

Comment: I don't understand why the image shows "Nodes in list: 11", even though only  8 words seem to be stored. 3 empty words?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you copying all the strings including the null character one after the other. You can the end the entire sequence with a double null. 
The only issue is that you are then force to access all the strings sequentially. If this is a problem you can use the beginning of the storage space to create an array of pointers to the start of all your string. It all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

put each string with '\0' in an array one by one,then use another array to save the index of each '\0'

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some sort of list indicating where each of the string starts and ends:

```
struct Node {
   int startOffset;
   int size; // includes trailing zero; 
             // (not really needed: can search for it with strlength)
};
```

And you want to write a function that, given a `vector<Node>` of the above and the char array with the strings (lets call it `chars`), shuffles strings around so that, for the ith node, `nodes[i].startOffset + nodes[i].size == nodes[i+1].startOffset`

You can do the following (assumes that the 0th node is at `startOffset` 0, and that the node vector is ordered by `startOffset`):

```
Node prev = nodes[0];
for (int i = 1; i<nodes.length(); i++) {
    Node n = nodes[i];
    int targetOffset = prev.startOffset + prev.size;
    memmove(chars + targetOffset, chars + n.startOffset, n.size);
    n.startOffset = targetOffset;
    prev = n;
}
```